# Threshold for pHash Image Similarity

Tags: image, image-processing, image-recognition, phash

I am trying find similar images using pHash comparison. pHash of an image is 64-bit number. What I am doing is comparing hashes of two images and then count the number of 1 in the resulting hash, then calculate the my result into percentage.
I have tried using 50% and 70% threshold, but got many FPs for 50% threshold and many FNs for 70% threshold. 
Which threshold will be better? Or do i need to perform some other calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's still relevant for you LOL, but 80% works for me. Maybe even 78%. But that depends on the size of your image matrix. If you're using the 'default' 64-bit matrix, that should work for you. If you're using a bigger matrix, the numbers will change.